# Invoke web service method inside Java Applet

Tags: java, webservice-client, applet

I succesfully builded a simple Java Web Service (as example you can refer to the ["Building simple web service"](http://www.roseindia.net/webservices/buildingsimplewebservice.shtml) )

In Eclipse is easy to create a web service client by using the "Java Web Service Proxy technique" indicated in the tutorial.

I want to run a Java Applet that do the same things of the java client application: access the web service, invoke the methods and return the results.

When i run the code by Eclipse (right click > "run as Java Applet..") everything works fine.. when i run the applet in a simple html page the applet start but goes in deadlock:
No exceptions are thrown, and the process is blocked without doing anything on the line that create the MyWebServiceProxy class, invoking the default constructor.

Can anyone help me in this?

I paste here some code to Let you understand better what i'm doing inside the applet:

```
public class SimpleWSApplet extends Applet {

 public void paint(Graphics g)
 {
  String msg = "Applet initialized";
  int i = 1;
  g.drawString(msg, 20, 20*i++);
  
  msg = "Error in applet";
  try {
   Service service = new Service();
   Call call = (Call)service.createCall();
   call.setTargetEndpointAddress("http://localhost:8080/AppletWSTest/services/SimpleWS");
   call.setOperationName(new QName("http://soapinterop.org/", "getMessage"));
   msg = (String)call.invoke(new Object[]{});
  } catch (Exception e) {
   e.printStackTrace();
   msg = "Error: "+e.getMessage();
  }
  g.drawString(msg, 20, 20*i++);
  //g.drawString(executeInvocation(msg), 20, 20*i++);
 }
}
```

Obviously my web service is called "SimpleWS" and the method that i invoke is called "getMessage", it takes no arguments, and returns a String.

Please help me..

Answer (score 3):

As you know, java applets are executed in a sandbox. By default, applets don't have any access to any web resource except from their original servers. Only signed applets can access such kind of resources. Therefore, you should [sign](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/guide/plugin/developer_guide/rsa_signing.html) your applet.

Comment: i signed the applet, wich now request for the certificate, but it says org.apache.axis cannot find my class while i'm sure it is inside the fatjar i created. Should i include jars in the "archive" porperty in the applet tag? if yes, wich one?

Comment: did you include axis classes to your signed jar?.. It looks like , these classes are not included.. And also, you can use jax-ws for web services, by this way, you dont need a third party library like apache axis.