# consume my SOAP web service through my java applet

Tags: java, html, web-services, soap, applet

I create a simple SOAP web service and I want to consume it using java applet....meanwhile I'm not sure if that is possible or not.  so my question is how to add this applet in HTML page and make it consume the web service also.  Does I have to take the web service generated sources and put them some where or I have to modify my normal applet tag.....

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to treat the generated source files any differently than your regular source files.  Simply copy the generated source files into your current project.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible...it is like using it from  a normal swing application cause you do not access local resources from the hosting computer.
Just bundle client code ...and will work.
I assume SOAP call is to a machine NOT different than that supplying the applet

Comment: So you mean that I had to take the .jar and the .class files and put them with the HTML page folder as normal and the web service will consume normally? if not can you clarify your point more as i can't figure it?

Comment: take a look here :http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4852654/invoke-web-service-method-inside-java-applet