# How can I call a WebMethod in Java Applet

Tags: java, c#, webmethod

How can I call a C# `WebMethod` in my `Java Applet` ?

The method called `EnrollClient` in C#

**My Try**

```
    public void enroll(String teste) {
       URL u;
       InputStream is = null;             

       try {
           u = new URL("http://localhost:5154/lb.ashx?pwd=abci/EnrollClient");
           is = u.openStream();
           BufferedReader d = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
       } catch (MalformedURLException mue) {              
               mue.printStackTrace();                 
         } catch (IOException ioe) {             
               ioe.printStackTrace();                
         } finally {
              try {
                    is.close();             
              } catch (IOException ioe) {               
         }
    }
```

**C# WebMethod**

```
public class lb : IHttpHandler
{
    public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
    {
        context.Response.ContentType = "text/plain";                        
        strings pwd = context.Request["pwd"].ToString();
        business.Client.lb cli = new business.Client.lb();

        JavaScriptSerializer jss = new JavaScriptSerializer();
        StringBuilder sbRes = new StringBuilder();                        
        jss.Serialize(cli.ReturnJSon(), sbRes);

        context.Response.Write(sbRes.ToString());
    }

    [WebMethod]
    public void EnrollClient()
    {
        string template = string.Empty;
        string client = string.Empty;
        try
        {
            business.Client.lb cli = new business.Client.lb();
            cli.EnrollClient(template, client);                                                
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
        }
    }
```

If I do the same code but with the code

`u = new URL("http://localhost:5154/lb.ashx?pwd=abci");`

it will access the `ProcessRequest` of my C# code.

Comment: Did you sign your applet? 


http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/guide/plugin/developer_guide/rsa_signing.html

Comment: No I don't, but I can do the following code: `http://localhost:5154/lb.ashx?pwd=abci` it works fine, but I'll access the `main` method of this `.ashx` file, and I need access a specific method called `EnrollClient`

Comment: This might help you.... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4852654/invoke-web-service-method-inside-java-applet

Comment: @JNL It will be really necessary ? I'm asking this because I can access the `ProccessRequest` method from my `lb.ashx` file, the problem is access another method in the same file.